# Inline SVG including external SVG but mask not applied

Tags: html, svg, cross-browser

I am considering to change the way I embed SVGs into my site. Currently, I am using `<img>` tags but they offer limited `transition` capabilities.

This is how I have structured my SVG graphics:

```
<svg xmlns... viewBox...>
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
      <!-- ... -->
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g fill... mask="url(#mask)">
    <circle...>
  </g>
</svg>
```

And this is how I am trying to embed them:

```
<!-- div -->
  <svg viewBox...>
    <use xlink:href="/path/to/image.svg"></use>
  </svg>
<!-- /div -->
```

Both Firefox and Chrome are displaying the circle in the filling color but only Firefox is applying the mask. This is unacceptable. Of course, I could move the `circle` into the inline SVG and reference the mask from there but I haven't tried that and I am not intending to.